# Visual Studio 2013: What do the number suffixes in the file tabs mean?

Tags: user-interface, tabs, visual-studio-2013

I just upgraded from VS2010 to VS2013 and now once in a while I will see a number in some of my tabs:

[image: Number in Tab]

I searched Google, MSDN and here with no avail to an answer.

Any idea what these numbers mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The numbers indicate different views of a file. You can open additional views from the main VS menu Window - New Window.

As for why they appear by themselves for .aspx files, it could be a bug in VS. I also heard about this problem from a colleague.

Comment: You are correct, I was able to open multiple windows of the same code file, with incrementing numbers. Thank you. For some reason the other tabs I have open with a number "1" do not have their companion code file open. When I close and reopen, it's gone. I'm sure this is a bug. Thanks again.

Comment: Nope. not even close.