# Why does Visual Studio show a :2 after the filename?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Has anyone seen this?

My solution today opened with this for the tab's filename:

```
<originalFilename>:2
```

This happens every so often and I'm wondering what's going on.

Comment: Can't confirm since I'm on my Mac right now, but if I recall correctly this is how VS makes a distinction when you have the same file open in multiple tabs (e.g. with a split window).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23999070/visual-studio-2013-what-the-numbers-in-tabs

Comment: That might be right, Sergey.  I can't reproduce it now.