# Visual studio file name on tab has an index

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, ide

I cannot find anything in the last releases of VS2017 related to a change in the way file names are displayed.
Sometimes I will get a colon followed by a 1 or 2 (`filename:1`, or `filename:2`) in the tab title, what does it mean? Does it have something to do with source control (TFS in this case)?

[image]

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23999070/visual-studio-2013-what-the-numbers-in-tabs

Comment: Oh so it's quite old.. Never seen it before. Could you please move your comment to the answer section so I can mark it solved?

Comment: It is better not to duplicate answers. And then it is an explanation, not a solution.

Comment: Ok. What are the rules on this, delete question?

Comment: On duplicate questions see https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/16/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/

Comment: I've started to see this now in VS2017... it happens when I switch branch in git. 

Never seen this before in the 5 years I've been using VS so maybe a bug?